# Perpendicular to orthogonal basis of Column space

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $q_1,q_2,\ldots,q_k$ be an orthogonal basis for the column space of a matrix $A$. Would it be correct to assume that if $W = \operatorname{span}\{q_1,q_q,\ldots,q_k\}$, then the basis for $\mathcal{N}(A)$ is perpendicular to $W$? Or is that incorrect?

I'm trying to figure out what would be perpendicular to $W$ and have a difficult time wrapping my head around it.

Answer (score 2):

First as a note, it doesn't matter if $W$ is spanned by an *orthogonal* basis for $\mathrm{col}(A)$. Any basis for $\mathrm{col}(A)$ pretty much by definition spans $\mathrm{col}(A)$ itself.

With that being said, you cannot say that the columnspace is orthogonal to the nullspace. It is true however that the rowspace is orthogonal to the nullspace. In fact, the rowspace and the nullspace form what are called [orthogonal complements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_complement) in the sense that the rowspace is exactly the set of vectors orthogonal to every element of the nullspace and vice versa.

Comment: How about the double perpendicular space ( perp space to perp space) to a subspace S? Why is it equal to the original S iff S is closed?